# Is there a way to return all pools containing a token symbol in Uniswap v3?

Tags: tokens, uniswap, swaps, factory

I am trying to get a list of all pools containing a token symbol with Uniswap v3 for arbitrage opportunities.  For example, if I want to find all pools containing "WETH".

Using the [subgraph](https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3),

```
{
    tokens(first: 10, where:{symbol:"WETH"}){
    id
    name
    symbol
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "tokens": [
      {
        "id": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
        "name": "Wrapped Ether",
        "symbol": "WETH"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Once I have a selected pool, I then will have `token0` and `token1` to use later in `factory.getPool()`.

Now to find the pools that contain WETH, I use the graph to check if `token0` OR `token1` contains the WETH ID, `0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2`.

```
// search token0
{
    pools(first:10, where: {
    token0:"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",            
}){
    token0{
      name
      symbol
      id
    }
    token1{
      name
      symbol
      id
    }
    }
}


// search token1
{
    pools(first:10, where: {
    token1:"0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",            
}){
    token0{
      name
      symbol
      id
    }
    token1{
      name
      symbol
      id
    }
    }
}
```

Now I have a list of all pools that that contain "WETH" and the pool ID's to use in factory to perform swaps.

So, what I would like to know is if there is a much simpler way of doing this please!?